# PascalCase React Snippet in VS Code

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, next.js, vscode-snippets, pascalcasing

I am using the "ES7+ React/Redux/React-Native snippets" extension VS Code. I like to use `rfc` to generate a React functional component based on the name of the file. The issue is I want to use Next.js / next router to handle my pages.

I want the route the browser hits to be `/blah/this-is-the-page` so the file needs to be `/pages/blah/this-is-the-page.tsx`. If I run the `rfc` snippet from this file it creates a function called `this-is-the-page` ie `export default function this-is-the-page() {`. The preferred behavior, when there are dashes in the file name, would be to use PascalCase like this: `ThisIsThePage` ie `export default function ThisIsThePage() {`.

Is there a way to customize or indicate to this snippet extension to use PascalCase in this situation?

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dsznajder.es7-react-js-snippets

Comment: I don't think you can; but when you use the snippet, your cursor is already at the function name and you can just change it.

Comment: you can add a find/replace to turn a dash-character to a Capital character